# How to play sound in c++

Tags: c++, audio

I was wondering how to play some default sound in c++. I do not want to download any additional files (programs nor music). Just to play 2 or 3 notes like bip bip. How should I write this code?

Comment: You should probably search for the same question in the forum, but with your operating system in the title, since usually C++ solutions are OS-dependent.

Comment: Standard C++ has no notion of sound (or graphics for that matter). You need to consume the OS-specific interfaces / APIs.

Comment: @user202729: Indeed; note that the accepted answer on the question you linked to explains that quibbling over the noun doesn't really do much.

Answer (score 1):

> How to play sound in c++

There is no standard API for playing a sound in C++. Operating systems that support sound provide an API (or several API's in some cases). First step in using the API is to figure out what operating system you're programming for.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("\a");
}
```

which will send the BEL signal to your terminal, which *normally* is a beep. That's been around since C89. But note that modern operating systems will have settings to suppress this, and you might need to resort to specific APIs.